# Preposition between "invoice" and "order"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Is *against* a correct and common preposition in the following sentence? Is there any frequently used preposition for this sentence?

> I have to create invoices **against** these orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brief time spent in the google finds that it's a standard accounting and auditing practice to check or match invoices *against* orders.  So your usage would be fine.  I found one vendor of software for suppliers (Ariba) that uses exactly that terminology in its documentation for generating invoices.

Comment: Thanks, I think the best answer. It shows that you really understand what the question is about.

Answer (score 1):

You can write *invoices **for** these orders*.

Comment: I am not writing these invoices, they are generated thru a Database in software

Answer (score -1):

In the following situations, *against* can be used as proposition.

1. **opposing or disagreeing with somebody/something**
2. **not to the advantage or favour of somebody/something**
3. **close to, touching or hitting somebody/something**
4. **in order to prevent something from happening or to reduce the damage caused by something**
5. **with something in the background, as a contrast**
6. **used when you are comparing two things**

[Source and example sentences.](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/against)

Therefore, it's not appropriate to use *against* as noted in OP. Moreover, the more proper verb here is *issue* rather than *create*.

"I have to ***issue*** invoices ***for/to*** these orders."

Comment: Meaning 6 makes the locution appropriate.  "Matching invoices *against* orders" is a common business practice.  And when software packages issue the invoices, the operator creates them.

Comment: The focus was on invoice and order. The info that you have provided can be easily found in any dictionary. Please be creative and do NOT just copy / paste dictionary entries.

Comment: You asked _"Is against a correct"_  and I answered no. Probably you do not want us to coin new things for you! Generally, a simple search could help you find what you are looking for as what @deadrat did!

Comment: Don't try to be wise guy please! We are here to help each other and learn something new. Moreover, if you think the answer(s) are not appropriate for your case, you probably need to know how to ask here, e.g. you should include your research and findings. We cannot foretell what you know and what you don't! Have a nice day